# Is this the correct definition of network framing?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

The way I understand network framing, it’s encapsulating data into a frame. That means taking a datagram and adding a header to it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

yes and no.

The terminology is a little muddy here, so without further elaboration, there is some debate in your definitions. From a highly abstract perspective, at any layer in the protocol stack, a 'packet' is a blob of data that contains a structured layout and the 'frame' is the structured layout for the protocol data unit at that layer, so a layer 6 packet contains a layer 6 'Frame'. This terminology is used on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet).

> A data packet on an Ethernet link is called an Ethernet packet, which transports an Ethernet frame as its payload. 
>   source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame

**This is NOT however the common terminology you will hear in relation to everyday IP networks or the Internet.**

In common parlance, when talking about modern data networks, especially in relation to the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), a Frame is specifically a Layer 2 PDU, so a Layer 3 Packet is encapsulated inside a frame, by placing the packet in the data region of the frame (and a layer 4 'segment' is encapsulated in the Layer 3 packet).

Wikipedia also touches on this terminology disparity:

> In the seven-layer OSI model of computer networking, packet strictly refers to a data unit at layer 3, the Network Layer. The correct term for a data unit at Layer 2, the Data Link Layer, is a frame, and at Layer 4, the Transport Layer, the correct term is a segment or datagram. For the case of TCP/IP communication over Ethernet, a TCP segment is carried in one or more IP packets, which are each carried in one or more Ethernet frames. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_packet#Terminology

The encapsulation process is much as you suggest; it is essentially prepending a header, and appending a trailer to the upper-layer data, but does involve calculations like a payload checksum based on the packet itself.

hope that helps.

Comment: The simplest description is perhaps that the data in each layer is encapsulated (framed) when it is repackaged for use in the next higher layer in the stack. When the data comes down the stack from a higher layer its is stripped of the encapulation so it can be understood by the lower layer.